# Large Chat app Mysql db message storage 1 row per message or append whole thread to 1 longtext feild

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigdata, chat

Were developing a large chat app using mysql db, conversations happen between only 2 people at any one time. 
Looking for opinions as to which db schema options would perform better.

Option 1. A traditional approach to insert one row per message/ response. 
          Simply inserting in a db which no prior lookups, however rebuilding
the chat thread would require ORDERBY

Option 2. Or to append each message to on single message field. 
          Would be faster selecting as there would be no need for ORDERBY
          However on every new message there would be a lookup 1st

Also with option 2 there would be less overall rows in the db

Any ideas?

Comment: Option 3 and only correct: two tables "conversation" and "single item"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've participated in designs of two large (in 10s of millions of active users) systems. Both used relational DBs for storage, one used MySQL. In both cases one message per row was stored. Indexing by `[thread_id, message_timestamp | message_sequential_number | message_auto_increment_id]` was fine for both fetching and ordering.

Keep in mind conversations may grow to multi-megabytes. If you store the entire conversation in a single row you will have to read/write the entire thing on each new message or keep the entire think in memory just to show maybe 50 last messages in most cases. Easily 200x inefficiency.

On the other hand, if you feel adventurous, take a look at Cassandra. It's designed for efficient storage of an entire conversation in one record.

Comment: Great insight, thanks for your thoughts gene, I have decided to go the the one message per row option...

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on what you want to do with the field.  In almost all cases, though, the first solution -- a separate row for each conversation -- is the right approach.

You would only want to use the second approach -- a single field for all of them -- if you were treating the conversation as a "blob".  That is, if you did not want to select particular messages, search within a message, and so on.  Essentially, the column would be an archive of the messages, rather that something as useful as another column.

I should also add that in a conversation, storing the messages in a single column loses the information of when the message was sent and who sent it.  Of course, you could try to encapsulate that, say by using a JSON column.  But why bother?  SQL already has good mechanisms for representing such information.

Comment: thanks for your input gordon. The app would work both ways as timestamps would by embedded in the message and displayed using JS. I was looking specifically for input relating to the db and performance of both options